# Help uninstalling virtualbox

Tags: debian, apt, virtualbox, delete

I am running Debian 10 and I installed VirtualBox, but now it won't go away. When trying to run `sudo apt purge virtualbox` I am met with the following output: `Virtual packages like 'virtualbox' can't be removed.` Someone please help!

`dpkg -l virtualbox\*` outputs:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                           Version                     Architecture Description
+++-==============================-===========================-============-=================================
un  virtualbox                     <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-6.0                 6.0.22-137980~Ubuntu~bionic amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
un  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose                 <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-qt                  <none>                      <none>       (no description available)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sudo apt purge virtualbox-6.0` or `sudo apt purge virtualbox*`

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox.
```

(with a dot at the end), it will remove all `virtualbox*` packages.